# How to use orderBy or filter to order by an object outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

Currently I have 2 functions (getFeeName and getFeeCategory) which I am using to return 2 sets of numbers and I am passing in value to those functions in order to retrieve lists.

I want to order the list by one of those sets of numbers that are being returned.

For example -

**HTML**:

```
<li ng-repeat="fees in feeBags | orderBy: 'getFeeCategory(fees)'">
  {{getFeeName(fees)}}, {{getFeeCategory(fees)}}
</li>
```

**Functions**:

```
$scope.getFeeName = function(fees){
    if (feeName = fees) {
      return name;
    }
  };
//returns [1,4,5,5]

  $scope.getFeeCategory = function(fees){
    if (feeCategory = fees) {
      return category;
    }
  };
//returns [4,3,1,2]
```

I want to orderby the results from getFeeCategory and I am not really sure how to do that outside of what I've already tried with track by or orderBy. Anyone have any idea if Angular let's you order by an object outside of the ng-repeat parameters?

Comment: try placing the orderBy filter in the `{{getFeeName(fees)}}, {{getFeeCategory(fees)}}` your code to filter by which ever one you are wanting to filter. I did something along those lines on an old project, hope it helps.

Comment: hmm so you're saying kind of like this `{{getFeeName(fees)}}, {{getFeeCategory(fees) | orderBy: getFeeCategory(fees)}}` ?

Comment: Are the single '=' in your if statements intentional? Or are they mean to be '=='?